# cuda- code doesnt enter the kernel

Tags: cuda

I am trying to learn cuda. I am trying to run a simple code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void kernel(int *array)
{
 int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

  array[index] = 7;
}

int main(void)
{
  int num_elements = 256;

  int num_bytes = num_elements * sizeof(int);

  // pointers to host & device arrays
  int *device_array = 0;
  int *host_array = 0;

  // malloc a host array
  host_array = (int*)malloc(num_bytes);

  // cudaMalloc a device array
  cudaMalloc((void**)&device_array, num_bytes);

  int block_size = 128;
  int grid_size = num_elements / block_size;

  kernel<<<grid_size,block_size>>>(device_array);

  // download and inspect the result on the host:
  cudaMemcpy(host_array, device_array, num_bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  // print out the result element by element
  for(int i=0; i < num_elements; ++i)
  {
    printf("%d ", host_array[i]);
  }

  // deallocate memory
  free(host_array);
  cudaFree(device_array);
}
```

It is supposed to print 7's but it prints 0's
This statement doesn't seem to get executed
    "kernel<<>>(device_array);"
 It doesn't give any compilation error also.
Any help ??

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code (apart from lack of error checking, which you should get into the habit of adding ASAP). Do the CUDA SDK examples run OK on your system ?

Comment: No obvious reason for failure. Add error checking to CUDA calls. Add `cudaDeviceSynchronize` after the kernel call and check its returned error code.

Comment: Which graphic device, CUDA toolkit and driver version have you installed?. Checking for errors is never a waste of time.

Comment: I did run the exact code here, and it prints 7's. I'm guessing a synchronization/driver/toolkit installation problem.

Answer (score 2):

The code runs fine on my machine, but make sure you add `cudaDeviceSynchronize` and error checking after the kernel call.

Change the code as follows to check for errors:

```
kernel<<<grid_size,block_size>>>(device_array);
// wait until tasks are completed
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

// check for errors
cudaError_t error = cudaGetLastError();
if (error != cudaSuccess) {
  fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: %s \n", cudaGetErrorString(error));
}
```